# how to delete a specific image in folder with symfony using unlink()?

Tags: php, symfony, unlink

I want to delete a specific image file in the folder web/img/users , i wrote this code :

```
$path = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/img/users';
unlink($path."".($employee->getImageName()));
```

but i have this error:

Warning: unlink(D:\wamp\www\QualiMaker\app/../web/img/users): Permission denied

[image]

Comment: ok , i did , so delete the negative vote if you did

Answer (score -1):

path example 100%

```
     unlink('../web/uploads/images/1c5033b5984e9c690e378cebacd16f60.jpeg');
```

Comment: Can you explain how this solves the permission problem?